# problem in multiple form validation bootstrap forms

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

i have at least two form in one page but all forms are dependent on the first form, The fields of the first form must be filled in order for the validation of the rest of the forms to work correctly.

what is problem?

my code: > [link](https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/WG16aep2TE8U/?ref=app)

Comment: no any solution?